# Reg is not recognized even I have set the environmental Variable

Tags: reactjs, loopback

when i install npm install -g loopback-cli than showing this error i have set environment variable like this C:\Python27\python.exe;C:\Program Files\nodejs\

[image: i]

Comment: Don't post text as screenshot. Post it as text.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Firstly download and install Microsoft Build Tools 2013 from :
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760 and run npm config  set msvs_version 2013 --global as suggested by catalint.
Delete the folder .npm-gyp under C:\Users\user
execute npm install -g fs --save-dev
Copy the downloaded fs folder from C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules to $nodehome\node_modules\npm\node_modules (Note : In my case its C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules)
execute npm install --msvs_version=2013 node-gyp rebuild
After doing above steps i stopped getting build errors.
```

Comment: i have followed  these but still not working getting same error again..

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Microsoft Build tools:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760